# Visual Studio 2012 SDK installation

Tags: sdk, visual-studio-2012, vsix

I have ultimate version of visual studio 2012 today I downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2012 SDK which suppose to add project templates under Visual studio new project dialog, but there is nothing displayed the only project template I see under Visual c#-> Extensibility is Visual studio package.
 can anyone help me out with this problem? I am using RTM version of VS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens because your target .NET framework version (at the top of the New Project Dialog) is set to something other than .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: Right forgot that I am using .Net 4.5 instead of 4.0 now so this was real case. but one question raising in my mind is, if I target 4.5 and create VSIX package will Visual Studio 2012 consumers be able to install and use that package?

Comment: Yes, but I presume you mean to ask about VS 2010. :) In that case, no...unfortunately you need to use VS 2010 and the VS 2010 SDK to build extensions that target both 2010 and 2012.